# Turn off hover state on specific submenu class

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have created menu with submenu. Submenu is show / hide on hover. Default is hide. Everything works ok. If submenu element `li` contains class `current_page_item`, jQuery show submenu that contains this class right after page load.

But when I hover trough the items of the menu, jQuery is closing and opening the submenu with `current_page_item`class and it is not working correct.

I want to reach the state when the submenu with `li` element with `current_page_item`  after page load will be showed and I can list trough the items in this submenu. Now it is jumping up and down and its hard to click on some submenu item.

Here is the fiddle. Item 3 is the problematic one.

https://jsfiddle.net/otrd7vbq/8/

Comment: You need to give active class to that element that already got opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>1 item</li>
  <li>2 item</li>
  <li class="hover"> 3 item
    <ul>
      <li>3a item</li>
      <li>3b item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hover">4 item
    <ul class="display-none">
      <li>4a item</li>
      <li>4b item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.display-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover").hover(function(){
    if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {
        $(this).children("ul").addClass("display-block");
    }
  }, function(){
        $(".display-none").removeClass("display-block");
  });
});
```

What you're basically doing is: **if the `li` tag has children, `display:block` them**

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wxpenwto/)

Comment: Ok, but I wanted the item 3 submenu be open right after page load. In your code are submenus closed.

Comment: @trenccan Woops my bad. You can take out `class="display-none"` from the first ul and it'll work as you wanted. I updated the answer.